# Error using wp_mail inside custom function

Tags: filters, email, wp-mail, fatal-error

I have this function that sends various emails for me:

```
function tps_send_email($emailTo, $subject, $content) {
    //Allow HTML in email
    function tps_set_html_email_content_type() {
        return 'text/html';
    }
    add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'tps_set_html_email_content_type' );

    //Send the email
    $mailSent = wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $content);

    //Reset HTML content type back to text only (avoids conflicts)
    remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'tps_set_html_email_content_type' );

    return $mailSent;
}
```

I use it so I don't have to set the content type manually each time I us wp_mail. But, if I use this function in another function more than once, like so:

```
function my_custom_function(){
    $mailTo = 'anemail@email.com';
    $subject = 'Some subject line';

    $emailTemplate1 = 'template 1 content goes here';
    tps_send_email($emailTo, $subject, $emailTemplate1 );

    if (some condition) {
        $emailTemplate2 = 'template 2 content goes here';
        //send another email
        tps_send_email($emailTo, $subject, $emailTemplate2  );
    }
}
```

The first email sends fine, but the 2nd email throws the error `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare tps_set_html_email_content_type()...` (which is a function within my `tps_send_email()` function).

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have put function **tps_set_html_email_content_type** inside the **tps_send_email**, and each time you call it, it will declare the **tps_set_html_email_content_type** function again. Just move it out:

```
function tps_set_html_email_content_type() {
    return 'text/html';
}

function tps_send_email($emailTo, $subject, $content) {
    add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'tps_set_html_email_content_type' );

    //Send the email
    $mailSent = wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $content);

    //Reset HTML content type back to text only (avoids conflicts)
    remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'tps_set_html_email_content_type' );

    return $mailSent;
}
```

I am not sure why you would put one function inside another one in the first place, but that is never a good idea, even so PHP supports it.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense and is a good rule of thumb. Thanks for the help!